# Css position content is not extending

Tags: jquery, css

I have content and I have form elements outside of content.I have moved form element to inside content using jquery prependTo function (if you click "Filtre Aç" button you'll see problem). But when I put inside content my content is not extending.I wanted learned to me how to fixed this problem ? so thanks.

My codes;

http://anitur.streamprovider.net/codepen/otel_filtreleme_cift.html

[image]

Comment: i can't see any `codepen` link.

Comment: where is the codepen link ?

Comment: I couldn't add codepen link that is why I upload my server you can see link which I edited

Comment: you can just add your html and css in question

Comment: okey link has been updated @Grundy

Answer (score 1):

that because your form have `z-index: 999` so you need to give your footer a zindex greater than 999 for example 1000, also if you want to move your footer to bottom just give it a fixed postion with `bottom: 0`

```
.listeleme-field-sayfa {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    font: 12px sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: white;
}
```

see this picture

[image]

Comment: but then form  stay under footer

Comment: and when I clicked "filtre Aç" button again big white space seems like  a problem

Comment: yes because your form too big depend on the div inside, try to do `.otel-filtre-kisim{overflow-y: scroll}` to scroll your div and form fitler

Comment: thanks for everything but I need to another way..this way distrups design..I have to put my form inside content without extending.thanks I am grateful to you.